# How are dynamic web applications hosted in containers?

Tags: kubernetes, web-applications, containers

May be a stupid question but I can't find an answer anywhere i've looked so far. If I am running a dynamic web application on a large scale using Kubernetes does each individual user/session require its own container? This may be a misunderstanding of dynamic web applications too but given that the server needs to handle the logic to display information relevant to the user how does this work when deployed in containers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web Servers can typically handle many concurrent requests at the same time.

When a user log in to a service to fetch some personal information from a database, a token or session cookie is typically sent with the request to the server. A Web Server handle many of these requests concurrently. But you may want to scale out the backend to many instances, depending on how much resources the web server is using.